# How to find the package conflicting with a command

Tags: fonts, xetex, errors

I am using a custom template given by my university for theses. In my text I use the `\mapstochar` command. Because of the template, I get the error message when compiling with XeLaTeX in Ubuntu:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \mapstochar
l.77 $\mapstochar
$
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
[1
]
\tf@toc=\write6
\openout6 = `test.toc'.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 79.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 79.
(./test.aux)
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 79.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 79.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryVeryEnd' on input line 79.
)
```

If I change the template to default or some conference's template, I don't get the error anymore. How can I find out which package/command is conflicting with `\mapstochar`?

The template requires the following packages

```
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\RequirePackage{ifxetex}

\ifxetex
\else
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\fi

\RequirePackage[absolute]{textpos}

% For conditionally including lists of tables and figures
\RequirePackage[figure,table]{totalcount}
\RequirePackage{color}
\RequirePackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{pdfpages}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{pbox}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{geometry}
\RequirePackage[pdfusetitle]{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\ifxetex
\RequirePackage[MnSymbol]{mathspec}

\RequirePackage{xltxtra}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\else
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{palatino}
\RequirePackage{mathabx}
\RequirePackage{mathpazo}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi
\RequirePackage{csquotes}
\ifxetex
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
\swedishenglish{
  \setmainlanguage{swedish}
  \setotherlanguages{english}
}{
  \setmainlanguage{english}
  \setotherlanguages{swedish}
}
\else
\swedishenglish{
  \RequirePackage[swedish]{babel}
}{
  \RequirePackage[english]{babel}
}
\fi
\RequirePackage{calc}
\RequirePackage{ragged2e}
\RequirePackage{carlito}
```

Comment: It does not seem to be a conflict, you just do not load the package that defines `\mapstochar`. `latexdef mapstochar` gives `\mathchar"3237` so you may want to add this definition if the class of your university doesn't have it for some reason.

Comment: `\mapstochar` is a standard `LaTeX` command, at least it is in TeXLive 2019. Therefore this error is very strange. Can you post a link to the template file (or the template file itself) here?

Comment: Please, add the whole error message that you find in the log file. It’s quite possible that it is *another* command that is undefined.

Comment: @egreg good point. I updated the text

Comment: @ZeinabGanjei OK, that's good. Now the problem is: why are you using `\mapstochar`?

Comment: it is defined by default so you have loaded a package that undefines it (probably because you are using a font set that doesn't have this character but you have given no hints about your packages or fonts)

Comment: @egreg I need it actually in a custom command ``\newcommand{\pfun}{\mathrel{\ooalign{\hfil$\mapstochar\mkern5mu$\hfil\cr$\to$\cr}}}`` to form a big arrow for some sort of transition.

Comment: `fdsymbol` and `mdsymbol` both undefine this character for example

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I edited the text. I would put the template but it's in a private repository and is too large to fit in here

Comment: @ZeinabGanjei That list of packages is really terrible, full of contradictions!

Comment: @egreg there are used in if-else statements. I don't know how to put them correctly here

Comment: and you appear to be using pdftex not xetex?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I use xelatex

Comment: why are you loading so many font packages? the main document font and main math font can only be one of them, loading multiple conflicting font choices at best means the earlier ones are ignored but more likely gives conflicting definitions.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't really know! the template is given to us by university. how should I correct it?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think the package ```MnSymbol``` in the template is unloading ```\mapstochar``` command. I tried to install ```MinionPro``` to solve the issue. But it cause many new and weird errors! Do you have any comments on that? Am I doing the right thing?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem after including `fdsymbol`. Following @DavidCarlisle's comment, I simply restored the definition of `\mapstochar` at the end of the preamble using:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\mapstochar}{\mathrel}{symbols}{"37}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!